# Retrieving arguments from HTTP_REFERER string

Tags: python, django

I am currently building a Python/Django application where I have a search function and is looking great.

`http://localhost:8000/search/?q=&start=Feb+13%2C+Sat&end=Feb+20%2C+Sat`

Then say I selected a link from the number of listed results the led me to the detail of the product whiche is another page. On the Django view of the product detail I captured the HTTP_REFERER using:

```
referer_url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
```

`referer_url` is now a string.

I wanted to retrieve the data included in the `referer_url` like:

```
start = self.request.GET.get("start") 
print start
```

Desired output is:

`Feb 13, Sat`

however I seem to have difficulty. Any ideas?

Comment: When forming a link on search results' page add the data you need to pass to product details to the link URL, so that in the Product details view you could access these data via `GET` dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`parse_qs` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs) of `urlparse` module:

```
import urlparse

parsed = urlparse.parse_qs(referer_url)
print parsed['start'][0]
```

the result would be:

```
Feb 13, Sat
```

Comment: Thank's Selcuk, I'll try is as soon as I get a chance.